# What to do when getting HTTP Error 500 and cannot edit articles in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, administrator

I am using Joomla 3.9.12 as an administrator since only three weeks for a small association. I have been updating the pages with no problem, but suddenly for one week, when going to the Control Panel and clicking on the articles, I get this message (translated from Swedish):

The page is not working at the moment.
[www.haparandapojkarna.com](http://www.haparandapojkarna.com) is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I do not have access to the global configuration site to see if I can find the problem. Can it be something else I might have changed in the menus/components/extensions etc?

Hope someone can help me.

I'm not sure what to write here as I described the problem in detail above...

Answer (score 0):

### Joomla Configuration

Go to FTP, look on **configuration.php.**

```
Chmod to 557
```

On configuration.php
change this variable to

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
public $debug = true;
```

***Save***

```
chmod again to 555
```

You can see the information of what source cause error.

### Force ini_set

or second ways. Go FTP, on **template\index.php**
add following code.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

## Security Mode

In a **LIVE SITE** (not [**!LOCALHOST**]). Always remember to be paranoid by setting the .htaccess to give access allow only on your **IP ADDRESS** and deny all incoming traffic. The **other experience** has documented how crawler and another engine can record your live site in **debug or INI_SET condition** which easy to use for an attacker.

**this all setting only for development mode.
if you forgot make the setting to default again.
You just make your site in expose by an attacker**